# Почему установщик JDK предлагает поставить рядом и JRE?

Tags: java

Дилетантский вопрос. Ставлю я, к примеру, jdk-8u102-windows-x64.

В инсталяторе есть опция - Public JRE.

Если её включить, то на выходе получаем папку jdk (внутри которой есть jre) и рядом с jdk - ещё одна папка jre. Папки jdk/jre и вторая jre очень похожи. Причём в jdk/jre даже немного больше файлов.

Для чего это вообще сделано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это же виндовс если нет жре в папке ждк последний не будет работать. так как не увидит жре

Comment: наверно неправильно меня поняли. я говорю про jre не ту, которая в jdk (jdk1.8.0_102\jre), а которая рядом ставится (jre1.8.0_102)

Comment: @Naumov или вы хотите сказать, что под никсами jre в jdk просто нет? Но там же есть Public JRE галка? Если её не ставить, то что jre вообще не копируется (но такого же быть не может)?

Comment: под like nix есть симлинки и пути системы, которые прекрасно работают, а в windows легче скопировать всё в папку, там к стати всё по отдельности есть jdk есть jre и т.д.

Comment: Ну хорошему, симлинки есть и на винде (mklink). Я как раз использую для Android Studio, ему почему-то важно, чтобы gradle была у него подпапкой.

Comment: @zRrr, наверно, вы правы. По крайней мере выглядит очень правдоподобно.

Comment: видимо потому что это разные сборки одной версии JRE. %JDK%\jre - может включать какие-то дополнительные функции которых нет в JRE которое поставляется отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zRrr прав. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#private
Здесь написано, что jdk/jre используется для инструментов только этого jdk, и никак не регистрируется в системе. 
Public Jre может использоваться другими java приложениями и добавляется в реестр windows, может быть удалено из панели управления.

Answer (score 0):

Public JRE нужен для интеграции Java с браузерами и для запуска Java приложений одним кликом. Если в этом нет реальной необходимости, лучше Public JRE не устанавливать.